# Python Vk_api не работает как надо

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Решил прочитать документацию,и нашел самый простой пример.

```
import vk_api

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi('********', '********')
vk_session.auth()

vk = vk_session.get_api()

print(vk.wall.post(message='Hello world!'))
```

При запуске:`AttributeError: module 'vk_api' has no attribute 'VkApi'`

Comment: У вас никакой ваш файл не называется vk_api.py ?

Comment: да называется,а это как то сказывается?

Comment: Я имею в виду, что нет конфликта имен с самой библиотекой?

Comment: Библиотека через pip install установлена?

Comment: Если у вас в папке с скриптом есть ваш файл `vk_api.py`, то при импорте `import vk_api` будет он импортирован, а не библиотека `vk_api`. Это называет конфликт имен. Поменяйте название вашего `vk_api.py` на другое и проблема будет решена